# Android App crashes when running on Windows 10 and VS2015 Android Emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, emulation

Been trying to figure this out for a while but with no luck...

**Background:**

I am trying to run a Xamarin.Forms application within an Android Emulator through Visual Studio 2015 (update 3) on Windows 10. I installed all the required Android SDK and also ran against different emulators ranging from 4.4 Kitkat to 6.0 Marshmellow and I get the same results. The app is built with Xamarin.Forms with the pages in a portable C#/XAML project. #rd paty library FreshMVVM is used for IOC and ViewModels

**Issue**

The app mostly starts up first time but I typically have to wait 20-30 sec after deploy to run the app otherwise the app crashes straight away but the real issue is that when I get to the first page with a button on it (navigating to LoginPageModel), clicking the button will crash the app. The logcat Android Device Logging Window prints out the following during the crash... (sensitive info masked)

Things I have tried:

- Removing constructor code from LoginPageModel class ... no change
- Removing XAML. Mostly works but experience is inconsistant. Maybe related to the Xamarin forms controls?
- Conrols used are: ContentPage, Image, ContentView, StackLayout, Entry, Label, Switch, Button

  D/Mono    ( 1585): Assembly Ref addref MyCompany[0xb7d43920] -> Xamarin.Insights[0xb7d3e690]: 3
  I/MyCompany.REALAPI( 1585): Constructing ApiService.
  I/MyCompany.LOGIN( 1585): AuthenticationRepositoryService is being constructed
  I/MyCompany.LOGIN( 1585): Instantiating new LoginPageModel.
  D/DonatelloNative_Selector(  134): Removing selector for fd 33
  W/InputDispatcher(  464): channel 'a94e5108 com.mycompany.feature/md5bf4894c535574ee8d52747007a18ed49.SplashActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
  D/DonatelloNative_Selector(  134): Removing selector for fd 32
  E/InputDispatcher(  464): channel 'a94e5108 com.mycompany.feature/md5bf4894c535574ee8d52747007a18ed49.SplashActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
  W/InputDispatcher(  464): channel 'a941cf20 com.mycompany.feature/md5bf4894c535574ee8d52747007a18ed49.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
  E/InputDispatcher(  464): channel 'a941cf20 com.mycompany.feature/md5bf4894c535574ee8d52747007a18ed49.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
  W/InputDispatcher(  464): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'a94e5108 com.mycompany.feature/md5bf4894c535574ee8d52747007a18ed49.SplashActivity (server)'
  W/InputDispatcher(  464): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'a941cf20 com.mycompany.feature/md5bf4894c535574ee8d52747007a18ed49.MainActivity (server)'
  I/WindowState(  464): WIN DEATH: Window{a94e5108 u0 com.mycompany.feature/md5bf4894c535574ee8d52747007a18ed49.SplashActivity}
  I/ActivityManager(  464): Process com.mycompany.feature (pid 1585) has died.
  W/ActivityManager(  464): Force removing ActivityRecord{a9308df8 u0 com.mycompany.feature/md5bf4894c535574ee8d52747007a18ed49.MainActivity t14}: app died, no saved state
  I/WindowState(  464): WIN DEATH: Window{a941cf20 u0 com.mycompany.feature/md5bf4894c535574ee8d52747007a18ed49.MainActivity}
  D/Zygote  (  139): Process 1585 terminated by signal (11)
  W/EGL_emulation(  692): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
  W/Binder  (  631): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
  W/Binder  (  631): java.lang.NullPointerException
  W/Binder  (  631):  at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
  W/Binder  (  631):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
  W/Binder  (  631):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
  W/Binder  (  631):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
  W/InputMethodManagerService(  464): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1585 uid 10054

Not sure if it is related to Hyper-V, the Emulator itself or the 3rd Party components.
Running the app as a Windows Universal app works fine.
Other machines running Windows 8.1 works fine also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this working though a change in the Hyper-V settings for the emulator.

Steps:

1. Open the Hyper-V Manager
2. Find the emulator under the list of Virtual Machines.
3. Right click the emulator entry and open it's settings.
4. As per image below, go to the Processor > Compatibility setting and ensure the "Migrate to a physcial computer with a different processor version" is checked

[image]